# Where did ViewErrorController.cs go?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I used dotnet core 2.2 and when creating a project i used to add custom validations in a error controller file that was made using the cli. now with version 7 this file is no longer there, where did it go?

i just tried to build a new project and the file was not there.

Comment: are you sure ViewErrorController is the framework type's name and not yours ?